Method to find the longest and shortest distance on a circle from origin with less computation

The sum of the least and greatest absolute value of $z$ which satisfies the condition $|2 z+1-i \sqrt{3}|=1$ is
A. 1
B. $\frac{3}{2}$
C. 2
D. none of these


In this problem, I'm able to reduce this problem to "finding $x,y$ such that they satisfy $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 +(y- \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2= (\frac{1}{2})^2$ and such that it maximize and minimize $x^2+y^2$, which is basically to find the closest and farthest point from origin to a circle with radius half and center $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$, which I can do with getting the equation of line joining the center and origin, and then solve for the values, but this is very computationally heavy and time consuming, is there a faster and easier way to do this?

Hint: You don't have to solve for the locations. How would you express the max/min distance in terms of the radius of the circle and the distance from origin to the center of the circle? Hence, the desired answer is ...  (just have to calculate 1 simple thing).

In order to minimize calculations interpret the question in terms of geometry in the complex plane.
Notice that $\lvert 2z+1-\mathrm i\sqrt 3\rvert =1$ and
$$\left\lvert z - \left (-\frac 1 2 + \mathrm i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right )\right\rvert =\frac 1 2$$
have the same solution, namely the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $c=(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$. This center is at distance $\lvert c\rvert =\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}}=1$ from $0$.
The line through $0$ and $c$ cuts the circle at its two (antipodal) points that are closest to and furthest away from $0$, respectively. The point on the circle closest to $0$ (midway between $c$ and $0$) has absolute value $\frac{1}{2},$ and its antipodal point has absolute value $\frac{1}{2}+(\text{circle diameter})=\frac{3}{2}$.
So C. 2 is the answer.

Yes.
If a circle has equation $|(x-a)+(y-b)i|=r$ then the distance from the origin to $(a,b)$ will be $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
The difference between the closest and furthest points on the circle from the origin will be $2r$ as a straight line from the origin through $(a,b)$ will pass through both of these points.
From there, you just need to know whether $(0,0)$ is interior or exterior to the circle to know whether the distance to the closest point will be $r-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ or $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-r$.
Once you have the distance to the closest point, add $2r$ to get the distance to the furthest point.
Let me know if a diagram would help clarify this and I can add one.
